# How can i put while in case?

Tags: javascript

Is there a problem with while inside case

```
case'usal':
                        d=
                        (while(s2>0)
                        {
                            sayi=sayi*s1;
                            s2--;
                        });
                        break;
```

Comment: What is the `d =` supposed to do? What are you expecting to be assigned to `d`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance in that case 'usal' my d is a variable that should be equal to s1^s2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `while`, just use `**` to raise `s1` to the power of `s2`:

```
case 'usal':
    d = s1 ** s2;
    break;
```